# Bottling hot sauces

Tags: sauce, canning, storage

Does anyone make bottles that can be sealed by canning method? I'll be making sauce in a few weeks and I'm looking for long term storage ideas without freezing or refrigeration. If everything else fails I'll just process in canning jars.

Comment: You may consider the bottles used for homemade beer with a [bail closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-top).  In the US, canning with bail closure jars is not common (as it is a **not recommended** method by USDA today, but [they once did](http://1.usa.gov/1HVSsR2)), but I have seen in use in France and Italy.

Comment: Have you searched online? They are quite easy to find.

Comment: I have. Maybe I'm not using the correct search terms? All I am coming up with is 5 ounce bottles with plastic lids and drip caps. On another note, why does this thread say 0 answers when I have received 2?

Comment: Papin, we used the bail closure bottles last year and they seemed to work fine for our personal use. In the future we would like to brand our sauces and sell them so I'm looking into slowly evolving into that. USDA is a PITA if you ask me.

Comment: Well, seems that you should get used to it (if you're in the US)... seeing as they'll close your operation down if you don't follow their rules and try to sell commercially. Have you considered looking at the cost of small-run commercial bottling? There are thousands of hot sauces out there that manage professional bottling.

Comment: Assuming you are in the US, I just searched _beer bottle bail_ and _beer bottle flip top_ on Google and Amazon and found hits.  Cheapest was about $3/bottle, a bit too expensive for commercial use.  I have no idea about your marketing strategy, what price point you are targeting, or how well your sauce keeps, but the bottle could easily dominate your costs.  By using fancier bottling techniques you can use cheaper closure methods.  You may also want to look at the question [How do I maximize the shelf life of my homemade hot sauce?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/25761/183)

Comment: Many recipes for hot sauce have a low enough pH, enough vinegar, that they don't need any canning or special sealing for long term exposure. If you look carefully at the hot sauces lining the shelves of your local supermarket, you'll see that many of them come with simple screw-tops, not even safety seals or plastic gaskets. You may be overthinking the regulation of hot sauce containers here in the US.

Comment: @papin that manual makes my head hurt - the typesetter apparently couldn't tell the difference between "a" and "o" in this font.

Answer (score 1):

I use the typical high acid method for canning.

Canning jars; new tops and then boiling water bath for 10-15 mins; never had an issue.  Although my hot sauce has never last over a year without being used. :)

Originally tried using bottles as other mentioned; was too painful to fill in kitchen for my small batches I do (5 gallons at a time).

If you are looking to sell higher volume, getting a [co packer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copacker) may be the easiest bet.